# Exporting fbx breaks rig

Tags: rigging, .fbx

[image]
[image]

The rig breaks when exporting to fbx and reimporting in any app. the first pick is before and the second is after

Comment: my quick question is, did you apply rotation to your objects before exporting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.